# keep current tab active after submit rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello all i am trying to keep the tab active after the submitting .. I am using rails how do i do it and

My View code

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs"  id="tabs">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#project" data-toggle="tab" title="Project">Project</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Requirements" data-toggle="tab" title="Requirements"  onclick="clickme(this,1,1)">Requirements</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#Governance" data-toggle="tab"  title="Governance"  onclick="clickme(this,1,2)">Governance</a></li>
                    </ul>  
                    <div class="tab-content">

                        <div class="tab-pane active " id="project">
                           <%= render 'project'%>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane " id="Requirements">

                           <%= render 'form'  %>
                        </div>
                 </div>
```

the script i am using is

```
$(function() {
  var json, tabsState;
  $('a[data-toggle="pill"], a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    var href, json, parentId, tabsState;

    tabsState = localStorage.getItem("tabs-state");
    json = JSON.parse(tabsState || "{}");
    parentId = $(e.target).parents("ul.nav.nav-pills, ul.nav.nav-tabs").attr("id");
    href = $(e.target).attr('href');
    json[parentId] = href;

    return localStorage.setItem("tabs-state", JSON.stringify(json));
  });

  tabsState = localStorage.getItem("tabs-state");
  json = JSON.parse(tabsState || "{}");

  $.each(json, function(containerId, href) {
    return $("#" + containerId + " a[href=" + href + "]").tab('show');
  });

  $("ul.nav.nav-pills, ul.nav.nav-tabs").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!json[$this.attr("id")]) {
      return $this.find("a[data-toggle=tab]:first, a[data-toggle=pill]:first").tab("show");
    }
  });
});
```

but its not working i am using bootstrap 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be overcomplicating things a bit. You can dynamically assign a class in an ERB view (which I assume this is) with something like:

```
<li class="<%= 'active' if params[:action] == 'project' %>">
```

This way to you don't have to fiddle with JavaScript to keep track of tab states.